# Datagrip не подсвечивает таблицы SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datagrip

Datagrip не видит таблицы, созданные в Microsoft SQL Server в других файлах
На скриншотах приведено объявление таблицы и попытка обратиться к ней в другом файле. Как это дело исправить?
К базе данных, в которой создаю таблицу, я, естественно, подключаюсь (скриншот 3)

[image: Создание таблицы]

[image: Обращение к таблице в другом файле]
[image: подключение к бд и использование её контекста]

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов:

1. Вам нужно создать DDL data source и расширить этими файлами MS SQL data source. Тогда будет работать аводополнение.
   [image: extend data source]
2. Подключить консоль с MS SQL data source к файлу SQL
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделал по вашему совету. также загуглил и нашел инструкцию на сайте JB. теперь код подсвечивается нормально, но только до того момента, как я подключаюсь к сессии. когда пытаюсь выполнить скрипт, подсветка снова слетает и надо отключаться от сессии, чтобы снова был подсвечен.

Comment: У вас там в скрипте есть USE?

Comment: @moscas да, есть

Comment: Та база, которая у вас изначально стоит в контексте должна быть прописана в свойствах коннекции как дефолтная.